# why does my j-unit testing for hashmap return 'expecting null pointer exception'?

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, hashmap, logic

im are suppose to make a histogram using hash map. we are to construct some junit testing but my tests come  back null. is it not sort of the same as testing for an empty string in an ArrayList?
also my first two tests should be expecting an illegal Argument, but even those fail..
usually we create an new object of that class and test the methods on it BUT when i create a histogram object i cant relate it to my hashmap logically or for testing. i done j unit testing multiple times but im drawing a blank here for hash map because its my first time using it. any suggestion? thx in advance.

```
 public class Histogram{

 private HashMap<String, Integer> map;

/**
 * constructor for Histogram
 * 
 * @precondition map cannot contain null or empty string values
 * @postcondition sets map to new Hashmap
 * @param none
 * 
 */
public Histogram() {

   if ((this.map.containsValue("") || this.map.containsKey(null)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "there cannot be an empty string an String cannot be null");
    }
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}
/**
 * attempts to find the parameter in map.
 * 
 * @param add
 *            the string to find
 * 
 */
    public void add(String add) {
    for (int count = 1; count >= 1; count++) {
        if (this.map.containsKey(add)) {
            count++;
        }
        if (!this.map.containsKey(add)) {
            this.map.put(add, 1);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * finds the count associated with the parameter and returns it.
 * 
 * @param count
 *            the count/number relevant to the key in the hashmap
 * @return countb, the count converted into a integer
 */
public int getCount(String count) {
    this.map.get(count);
    int countb = Integer.parseInt(count);
    if (!this.map.containsKey(count)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return countb;
    }
}

/**
 * sorts the words in the list returned
 * 
 * @return keys a sorted list of keys in the hashmap maps
 */
public ArrayList<String> getSortedKeys() {
    ArrayList<String> keys = null;
    keys = new ArrayList<String>(this.map.keySet());
    Collections.sort(keys);
    return keys;

}


j uint testing class

public class WhenAddingToHistogram {

private HashMap<String, Integer> map;

/**
 * test for adding an empty string
 */
@Test
(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testForAddingemptyString() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //Histogram database   = new Histogram();

    this.map.put("kassy", 1);
    this.map.put("sid", 2);
    this.map.put("", 3);
    assertEquals(this.map.containsKey(""),true);
}


/**
 * test for adding an empty string
 */
@Test
(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testForAddingNullString() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //Histogram database   = new Histogram();

    this.map.put("kassy", 1);
    this.map.put("sid", 2);
    this.map.put(null, 3);
    assertEquals(this.map.get(null), true);
}

/**
 * test if hash map contains key
 */
@Test
// (expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testForcontainskey() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.map.put("kassy", 1);
    assertEquals(this.map.get("kassy"), 1 , 0);
}

/**
 * test is hash map does not contain key
 */
@Test
//(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testFornotcontainskey() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.map.put("kassy", 1);
    this.map.put("joe",  2);
    assertEquals(this.map.containsKey("john"), false);
}
```

Comment: In your constructor, you don't even initialize `map` before you call methods on it.  That's why you're getting an NPE.  Further, your test shouldn't need to set internal data structures that your object requires to operate; it may need *data*, but you shouldn't need to pass it a new `Map`.

Comment: You're also writing your tests directly to the `Map` instance instead of your `Histogram` object.  `Map` works.  You want to see if `Histogram` works.

Comment: right! but i wasnt sure how to test my histogram object with my map... i believe i cant see the relation between the histogram and the hashmap object witch is why my logic for testing is jumbled up. in my constructor, my conditions are for hashmap. but how do i test hashmap through my constructor object?

Comment: You...don't.  You use the constructor to build the object.  There really shouldn't be anything to test in that (you probably don't need a non-default constructor).  As explained in my answer, you would want to test similar logic in a method you create to add your values into your `Histogram` object.  The map is going to accept most whatever it can handle within reason.

Comment: is there a way for me to edit my code so that i can show you the other methods/changes i have made?

Comment: im new to the site, so im trying to figure my way around around it. thx again

Comment: The edit link is at the bottom of the tags.

Answer (score 1):

This logic is misplaced and/or incorrect:

```
if ((this.map.containsValue("") || this.map.containsKey(null)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "there cannot be an empty string an String cannot be null");
}
```

If you want to ensure that no empty keys get inserted into your map, you should do that on a method that is called to place data in the histogram.  This makes the integrity check moot, as you won't have `null` or empty strings in your `Map`.

What's happening is that you're running the above logic before you *instantiate* your map instance.  It's going to be `null` at the point in instantiation when you're running the above logic.  It'd be better if you just directly instantiated it in the field instead:

```
map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: are you saying i should set my instance variable before i call my condition statements?  i was told that we do checks with conditions first, then set your instance variables so that the minor errors would be caught first

Comment: The condition you describe is impossible - you want to check your data structure before you have a data structure to check against.  You *really* do want to do this sort of validation check when you're doing the insertion.

Comment: ok so my error lies in my condition statement. but what other way to ask the map if it contains an empty string?  i seems right. is it because im checking for a value not a key in the first condition?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem here is a rather subtle one.

the usual way to test for boolean conditions in JUnit is (I believe), to call either `assertTrue` or `assertFalse`. However, what you are doing is calling assertEquals, which [based on the documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html), has no overload for booleans, just objects and a few other primitives.

Why is this important though?

Java does something under the covers called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)
. What this does is, whenever you give a primitive to a method that is expecting an object, Java automatically converts that primitive into an Object wrapper (ints get boxed into Integers, booleans into Booleans, etc). I believe that in your code, when you are calling

```
assertEquals(this.map.containsKey("john"), false);
```

what Java is doing is autoboxing the false value into a Boolean object, and then trying to call .equals on it with the first object. This is likely the source of your nullpointer.

Comment: Check the constructor.  What happens to fields at instantiation time if they aren't instantiated?

Comment: @Makoto i don't see the problem. doesn't he create the map at the beginning of every test method?

Comment: ...If you could justify the point to testing `Map`, then you'd probably be correct.

Comment: @Makoto I believe that's something OP put in order to check if the tests were even right in the first place. Notice how originally he had Histogram in those methods, but then commented it out because (presumably) he had the error he is getting.

Comment: @clearlyspam23 my whole objective is testing whether or not  if my hashmap contains a string or is null, but i dont know how to test it on my histogram object i made in junit testing methods. im expecting am illegal argument but i dont get one